# highchart not displaying in the center on mobile screen

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, highcharts, bootstrap-4

The stacked bars of highcharts are not displaying in the center of Mobile Screen.it is right aligned. can anybody give the solution to this problem? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="container" style="min-width: 100%; max-width:100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        marginLeft:120,
        marginBottom: 100,
        type:'bar'
    },
    credits: {enabled: false},
    legend: { 
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        margin: 50
    },
    title: {text: null},
    tooltip: {},
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        color: '#006666',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        color: '#00FF00',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        color: '#FF8C00',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Computer Devices & Accessories', 'Computer Peripherals Hire & Repair Services', 'Computer Laptop Hardware & Peripherals', 'Computer Stationery, Hard disk, Ram, Pen Drives & Other Products', 'Internet Accessories'],
        labels: {
            overflow: 'right',
            display: 'block',
            align: 'left',
            x:5,
            style: {
                fontSize: '1em',
                color:'#000',
                width:'500px'
            }
        }

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
    }       
});



    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Are there any specific configurations for the Mobile devices, If yes what exactly are they? Do I have to custom style it or if there are some configurations that may make it work? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your 'marginLeft' in script. You can set the margin in array so it will be nice centering on mobile. Also all your script tag should be in on bottom of body.

See code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="container" style="min-width: 100%; max-width:100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        /* marginLeft:120, */
        /* marginBottom: 100, */
        margin: [30,30,30,30],
        type:'bar'
    },
    credits: {enabled: false},
    legend: { 
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        margin: 50
    },
    title: {text: null},
    tooltip: {},
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        color: '#006666',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        color: '#00FF00',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        color: '#FF8C00',
        pointWidth: 40,
        data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Computer Devices & Accessories', 'Computer Peripherals Hire & Repair Services', 'Computer Laptop Hardware & Peripherals', 'Computer Stationery, Hard disk, Ram, Pen Drives & Other Products', 'Internet Accessories'],
        labels: {
            overflow: 'right',
            display: 'block',
            align: 'left',
            x:5,
            style: {
                fontSize: '1em',
                color:'#000',
                width:'500px'
            }
        }

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
    }       
});



    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if you want to dont change the marginLeft on full screen, you can use responsive option:

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo:'container',
    marginLeft:120,
    marginBottom: 100,
    /* margin: [30,30,30,30], */
    type:'bar'
},
responsive: {
    rules: [{
    condition: {
        maxWidth: 600
    },
    chartOptions: {
        chart: {
        marginLeft: 0
      }
    }
  }]
},
```

See more at [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/responsive)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `margin:0` instead of `marginLeft` and `marginBottom`

There are a couple of ways to fix this issue. I think the best one is to remove `marginLeft` and `marginBottom` but instead use `margin: 0`.

```js
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  /* marginLeft:120, */
  /* marginBottom: 100, */
  margin: 0,
  type: 'bar'
},
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 100%; max-width:100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          /* marginLeft:120, */
          /* marginBottom: 100, */
          margin: 0,
          type: 'bar'
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: true,
          layout: 'vertical',
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
          floating: true,
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          margin: 50
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        tooltip: {},
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'John',
          color: '#006666',
          pointWidth: 40,
          data: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          color: '#00FF00',
          pointWidth: 40,
          data: [2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
        }, {
          name: 'Joe',
          color: '#FF8C00',
          pointWidth: 40,
          data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        }],
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Computer Devices & Accessories', 'Computer Peripherals Hire & Repair Services', 'Computer Laptop Hardware & Peripherals', 'Computer Stationery, Hard disk, Ram, Pen Drives & Other Products', 'Internet Accessories'],
          labels: {
            overflow: 'right',
            display: 'block',
            align: 'left',
            x: 5,
            style: {
              fontSize: '1em',
              color: '#000',
              width: '500px'
            }
          }

        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          allowDecimals: false,
          title: {
            text: ''
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to add `margin`, use Bootstrap's spacing classes to add space for the `container`.

You should use `col-12` instead of `col-md-12` because there is only one column inside row. And  instead of `*-width` and `margin:auto`, use `w-100`. Since its width is `100%`, it is unnecessary to use `margin:auto`. But if you want to add `margin`, use `m-*`.

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px;" class="w-100 mx-sm-5"></div>
```

Doing so, you have more options and it is a lot easier and intuitive to do so.